# I am getting error in OneToMany relations?

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to make a relation between two entities, but the one of them is inherited.
So i have a Classroom class:

```java
@Entity
public class Classroom {

    @Id
    private int number;
    private int floor;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
    private List<Teacher> teachers;

}
```

and Teacher class, which extends Employee:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="teachers")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Teacher extends Employee{

    private int lessons;
    @ManyToOne
    private Classroom room;
    
}
```

I get the following error, when I try to run this code:

```
mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.example.demo.entities.Teacher.room in com.example.demo.entities.Classroom.teachers
```

Answer (score 2):

> mappedBy reference an unknown target **entity** property

gives us some idea on what is going wrong.

Your POJOs should be `@Entity`s, in order to be enabled as persistent classes; therefore, you should annotate your `Teacher` class with `@Entity`, like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Teacher extends Employee {

    //you might also consider having PK

    private int lessons;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Classroom room;

}
```

Beware!, that if your super-class (that is `Employee`) has some persistent state, it will not be enabled to the JPA for being ORM-ed, by default, on its own. For the latter purpose, you will need `@MappedSuperclass` on top of your super-class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your Teacher class needs to be declared as an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Teacher extends Employee
```

If you're using hibernate.cfg.xml you'll also need to declare the Teacher class there:

```
<mapping class="com.example.demo.entities.Teacher"/>
```